# How to download URL using youtube_explode_dart package in 2023?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I want to download videos using `audioOnly` from youtube using URL, I am using `youtube_explode_dart` for this purpose, but the code method has migrated now, I cant figure out despite checking documentation of package, that how to download audio only.

my code:

```
Future<String> getDownloadUrl(String videoId) async {
var youtube = YoutubeExplode();
var video = await youtube.videos.get(videoId);
return youtube.streamsClient.getAudioOnly().first.url;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it right but with old methods, update your code to the following mentioned, also check latest `youtube_explode_dart` package's documentation to understand better.

```
Future<String> getDownloadUrl(String videoId) async {
var youtube = YoutubeExplode();
var video = await youtube.videos.get(videoId);

// Get the stream manifest for the video
var streamManifest = await youtube.videos.streamsClient.getManifest(videoId);

// Get the audio-only streams from the manifest
var audioOnlyStreams = streamManifest.audioOnly;

// Get the highest quality audio-only stream
var audioStream = audioOnlyStreams.withHighestBitrate();

// Return the URL of the audio stream
return audioStream.url.toString();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

As in the official documentation, it's mentioned that audioOnly properties just we can use for this purpose only. > highest bitrate audio-only stream. You can check out the official document once again for more info.
https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_explode_dart

```
// Get highest quality muxed stream
var streamInfo = streamManifest.muxed.withHigestVideoQuality();

// ...or highest bitrate audio-only stream
var streamInfo = streamManifest.audioOnly.withHigestBitrate()

// ...or highest quality MP4 video-only stream
var streamInfo.videoOnly.where((e) => e.container == Container)
```

Comment: this nowhere answers my question, i already mentioned documentation is making me confused. Maybe show me where I can change my code to download audio only

Comment: To do that you have to change the code of that plugin. But It's a complex task. May be downloading audio may not possible. And also another option is there you can go to github repo of this plugin and open an issue. The developers will response you with a solution.